# Incorporating a Custom Grid with the Rally SDK

Tags: rally

There are a few things that the custom grid does that you cannot do with tables in the Rally SDK-- specifically re-ranking items.

For an app that I am making, incorporating a custom grid would work well, but I would like to be able to configure them programatically-- e.g. set up column names and widths, query parameters, etc. and then have that be a portion of my app-- I might set up a few grids in the app with different query parameters.

It that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.  Yet.

We are working hard on a shiny new App SDK based on the Ext JS Framework.  It will have a lot of the same features you are familiar with in Rally (like the grid w/ re-ranking, inline editing, etc).

Watch for it later this spring/summer!

Comment: How much work would you expect it to be to convert an existing app to the new app framework when it arrives?

Comment: Hopefully not much.  We are going to try to create some migration guides and rewrite some of the old app examples using the new SDK so you can see a side by side comparison.  We are trying to keep the spirit of the new SDK in line with the old one, but there will not always be a 1 to 1 translation between the old and new code.